# How do I create a custom Discord web modal?

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, browser, discord

I would like to create a custom Discord modal in it's web version (I'm creating a Chrome Extension, extension usage will not be disclosed.)

No -- not the bot modal, a modal that would appear when you're about to log out.

I didn't try anything yet because I didn't know where to start.
Discord has no docs on their `webpackChunkdiscord_app` class.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @AliNavidi My current question seems detailed enough. There isn't anything else to specify. I want to create a modal, like the one you see when you're about to logout in discord. Just hit the logout button and you'll see which modal I mean.